# Message brokers vs reactive approach

Tags: spring, meteor, rabbitmq, reactive-programming, messagebroker

There seems to be two technnology approaches, aimed to the same goal. Multicast and instant update of web app users terminal data. Message brokers,like Rabbit MQ, and reactive apps like Meteor.js, Spring 5 reactive stack.

What are pros and cons.

Comment: What do you think is the "same goal" of multicast and reactivity?

Comment: Push-like near real time updating of user screens with new data. Like financial trading apps or messengers like whatsapp.